# Adding resposivity to image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am learning how to create image slider from scratch. Functional side is all good . But i would like make slider responsive. If you open fiddle link, and try to resize window (when first image is displayed), then you can see, what i want to achieve for all slides. press next or prev, resize window, then u will see whats the problem, other images are stretching in slider area...  So, is there anyway i can make this version responsive ? Or should i build it differently ?

p.s next part of image is visible, so user can also click on next image . It is how it should be .

Here is fiddle . http://jsfiddle.net/DkFnL/

part of code  -

```
gallery-wrapper
{
    border-left:220px solid rgb(243,239,223);
    height: 75%;
}
#gallery-menu
{
    width:220px;
    margin-left: -220px;
    text-align: center;
}
#slider
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slider ul
{
    width: 750%;

}
#slider ul li 
{
    width:10%;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#slider ul li img
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It'd be easiest to use a different means most likely. You might try changing everything to percents (particularly the margin-left) before trying another means though

Comment: i need that gallery-menu in fixed width . But gallery wrapper dynamic width . Thats the solution what i found on css-tricks . Also if i give slider width of 85% and gallery-menu 15% , thing stays the same . So it doesnt solve anything. Question here is , how others create responsive sliders ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create another div like this
HTML

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="sliderscroll">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="assets/img/gallery/sliderimg1.jpg" alt="sliderimg1"></li>
            <li><img src="assets/img/gallery/sliderimg2.jpg" alt="sliderimg2"></li>
            <li><img src="assets/img/gallery/sliderimg3.jpg" alt="sliderimg3"></li>
            <li><img src="assets/img/gallery/sliderimg4.jpg" alt="sliderimg4"></li>
        </ul>
   </div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
#sliderscroll{
    width:750%;
    left:0px;
}
#slider ul
{
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

and then change your function to percentages like this
Javascript

```
function transition( container, loc, direction) {
  var unit; // vai nu + vai -, lai zin uz kuru pusi jaiet
  if (direction && loc !== 0)
  {
        unit = ( direction === "next") ? "-=" : "+=" // tas pats kas if
  }
    container.animate({
        "margin-left" : (unit ? (unit + 10) : 0)+"%",
        "left":(unit ? (unit +5) : 0)+"px"
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DkFnL/2/

Answer (score 0):

I inspected other responsive sliders out there. It turns out that the main thing which i need to change, was negative margine in jquery.animate, which i used for image display. Changed it from px to % .